# Angular 2 + Spring MVC

Tags: angular

Angular2 application works with Spring MVC under Tomcat and has url "/angular/index.html".

I use   base `href="/angular/index.html"`.

Router has redirectTo: `'/login'`.

Full url: `"/angular/index.html/login"` and all work fine.

My questions:

1. Is it possible to use `"/angular/login"` instead of `"/angular/index.html/login"`?
2. After refresh `"/angular/index.html/login"` I get 404 Not found. How can I fix using spring controller or servlet?

Comment: Show your router file

Answer (score 0):

Add one more entry in your router for "/angular/index.html/login" url and give the same controller on which  href="/angular/index.html" is being redirected.